# Using onclick with multiple buttons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In my long, multi-page HTML document, I want to include multiple buttons that look the same and do the same thing (location.reload();).  With the idea of not repeating code, I would like to make a single onclick event that works for all of them.  But I can't figure out how.

I've tried playing with giving them all the same .class of "reloadButton" instead of an id, such as `<button class="reloadButton">Reload</button>`.  Then I tried to use `var reload = documents.getElementsByClassName("reloadButton");`.

But I don't know what to do from there.  Trying something like 
`reload.onclick = function () { location.reload(); }`  doesn't seem to work.

I'm not sure how to use a for loop to go through all the array-like HTMLCollection when it's attached to the onclick event.

This is with just pure JavaScript and my level of expertise is pure beginner too.  So, I would love it if you might be able to explain it with that in a mind or if you could link a website that explains this at a level I might be able to understand.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you using jQuery or pure javascript?

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate because you're asking how to loop through an array-like structure, which is answered in the linked question. Adding event listeners is technically a separate question, but again it's one that's been asked many many times.

Comment: No, he is asking how to assign the same functionality to many buttons with the same class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED VERSION**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the page has loaded
  document.getElementById("NearestStaticContainerForButtons").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("reloadButton")) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stop the button if not type=button 
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

**Older versions**

Plain JS:

```
window.onload=function() { // when the page has loaded
  var bt = document.querySelectorAll(".reloadButton"); // get all buttons with the class
  for (var i=0;i<bt.length;i++) { // newer browsers can use forEach
    bt[i].onclick=function() { // assign anonymous handler
      location.reload();
    }
  }
}
```

or with a named function

```
function reloadPage() {
  location.reload();
}
window.onload=function() { // when the page has loaded
  var bt = document.querySelectorAll(".reloadButton"); // get all buttons with the class
  for (var i=0;i<bt.length;i++) { // newer browsers can use forEach
    bt[i].onclick=reloadPage;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Couple of questions :
1.  why querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByClassName 
2.  is the window.onload required?  I experimented without it and it worked also.  So curious if it's needed.

Comment: 1: querySelectorAll is more compatible and standard than getElementByClassName 2. if you place your script at the en of the page after the last button, the window.onload is not needed, otherwise it is

Comment: Ps: I'm off to bed

Comment: Thank you, again, mplungjan!  So is it considered best practice to use querySelectorAll() over getElementsByTagName() and getElementsByClassName() in all instances?  If not, can you link a site where I could read up on when to use each one in terms of best practice?

Comment: Have a look at caniuse- also I would personally standardise on one method. Bonus: easy to convert to jQuery selector

Answer (score 0):

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-say-hi');
var displayBox = document.querySelector('.js-display-greeting');

// wire displayGreeting function to each button with .js-say-hi class
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', displayGreeting)
}

function displayGreeting(event) {
  var buttonNumber = event.target.textContent[event.target.textContent.length - 1];
  displayBox.textContent += 'hello from button ' + buttonNumber + '! ';  
}
```

```html
<button class="js-say-hi">Say hi 1</button>
<button class="js-say-hi">Say hi 2</button>
<button class="js-say-hi">Say hi 3</button>
<button class="js-say-hi">Say hi 4</button>
<button class="js-say-hi">Say hi 5</button>
<div class="js-display-greeting"></div>
```

Comment: Why answer with unrelated code? Also addEventListener is not supported by older IEs

Answer (score 0):

you can also just use the named function

```
function reloadPage() {
  location.reload();
}
```

and then instead of

```
<button class="reloadButton">Reload</button>
```

use

```
<button onclick="reloadpage();">Reload</button>
```

Comment: However that is inline in every single button. Not recommended

Comment: I didn't know, why is that?

Comment: Because you need to separate markup from code (MVC)